# My function is not printing anything

Tags: javascript

The algorithm is supposed to sum two elements of the array and insert them between the two elements used in the sum.

Example input ==> output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] ==> [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4]
```

```js
function growArray() {
    var sequence = [];
    sequence = window.prompt("Enter a number sequence", "1 2 3 4");
    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i += 2) {
        if (!((i + 1) in sequence)) {
            return;
        } // prevent out of bounds access
        var new_value = sequence[i] + sequence[i + 1];
        sequence.splice(i + 1, 0, new_value); // insert value at i + 1
    }

    for (var v in sequence) {
        document.write(v + ", ");
    }
}
```

```html
<p>
    <input id="f1" type="button" value="Function 1" onclick="growArray();" />Click to expand array
</p>
```

Comment: `if (!((i + 1) in sequence))` is not going to work, since sequence is just a string. `.split(" ")` if that's the expected input.

Comment: Make sure you check the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand sequence

Comment: Add `.split(" ")` to your prompt: `sequence = window.prompt("Enter a number sequence", "1 2 3 4").split(" ");`

Comment: *Note:* I would avoid the use of `document.write()` in this case, since the DOM already loaded this will remove the entire DOM with the items in `document.write`. Instead place the output in an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what gets the output

```js
function growArray() {
    var input = window.prompt("Enter a number sequence", "1 2 3 4");
    var sequence = input.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i += 2) {
        if (i + 1 > sequence.length) {
            return;
        } // prevent out of bounds access
        var new_value = parseInt(sequence[i]) + parseInt(sequence[i + 1]);
        sequence.splice(i + 1, 0, new_value); // insert value at i + 1
    }
    document.write(sequence.toString());
}
```

```html
<p>
    <input id="f1" type="button" value="Function 1" onclick="growArray();" />Click to expand array
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `split` user input into an array (sequence).

This array contains string values because user input is string. 
So you have to map those values in int, in order to add them.

```
var sequence = '1 2 3 4'.split(' ').map(Number);
for(var i=0; i<sequence.length - 1; i+=2) {
    sequence.splice(i+1, 0, sequence[i] + sequence[i+1]);
}
document.write(sequence.join(', '));
```

working [example](http://codepen.io/pbaris/pen/meMZqg?editors=001)

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to look upon your code.

`sequence` is an array, but you did not defined a type, or even parsed the inputs. It is a String array as far as I can read.

> [Documentation states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

Then, your array keeps getting altered while you work on it. While this is no error, it is "weird" for the task at hand, and the apparent dominium you have over the language.

```
example(){
   var original = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   var result=[];
   for(var i=0;i<original.length;i++){
      result.push(original[i]);
      if(i<original.length-1){
         result.push(original[i]+original[i+1]);
      }
   }
   alert(result);
}
```

Comment: I don't see why I'd have to create a whole new array to do this task. Please check my answer, it looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: You dont have to. It is generally advised to keep each variable with a single type. In javascript you can do this: `var something = true;`, then `something *=3`, then `something ="a string now";` this makes debugging and maintaining the code very difficult. So, you should have one array for Strings, one for Number... the accepted answer is a code that "works" as in does what the question asked. However, if you input "1, 2, something" your code will yeld wrong results `1,,3,2,,NaN,something`. It is important to know that users are... special... and they will never read/comply if your questions